# Flutter Displaying Elements from an Array by Date range

Tags: android, flutter, dart, date

How to make date display after range from To ?

```
List<Odpowiedzialni> getFilteredItems() {
    List<Odpowiedzialni> filteredList = _inwentaryzacja_tabela
        .where((item) =>
            item.uzytkownik!
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
            item.nazwiskoImie!
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
            (item.uzytkownik! + ' ' + item.nazwiskoImie!)
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();

    // filteredList.sort((a, b) {
    //   try {
    //     DateTime dateA = DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(a.wazneOd!);
    //     DateTime dateB = DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(b.wazneOd!);
    //     return dateA.compareTo(dateB);
    //   } catch (e) {
    //     return 0;
    //   }
    // });

    if (_selectedDateRange != null) {
      filteredList = filteredList.where((item) {
        try {
          DateTime itemDate =
              DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(item.wazneOd!);
          DateTime startDate = _selectedDateRange!.start;
          DateTime endDate = _selectedDateRange!.end;
          return itemDate.isAfter(startDate.subtract(Duration(seconds: 1))) &&
              itemDate.isBefore(endDate.add(Duration(seconds: 1)));
        } catch (e) {
          return false;
        }
      }).toList();
    }

    return filteredList;
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTFQB.png)

Date format from My database is given in the picture under the link

When I select data from my date picker it doesn't show me the right data..